# Why SSD training doesn't give accurate resullt

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to detect human head including neck and shoulder using [single-shot multibox detector (SSD)](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd).
I have about 800 images and trained for 50,000 iterations.
But in detection, detection_eval has maximum 0.29 during training.

In deployment, there is no accurate detection.
What could be the issue?
My rectangles are around 40 x 40 pixels.

One of the images tested is attached.

The image is shown [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aoqaugnosf6s1bh/detect_result.jpg?dl=0)

Is it too small number of training images or object size is too small for SSD?
What could be the issue?

Since my PC is not powerful, I used only 3 batch size, would it be issue?

It does converge in training from loss 60 to loss ~0.9 during 50,000 iterations.

Comment: This is the page `https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe`

Comment: Sorry pls see here `https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd`

Comment: It is difficult to know what exactly the problem is. My guess is that you have too few training samples

Comment: @Shai I used the same number of training samples for Yolo. It does pretty good.

Comment: @Shai would it be the issue of object sizes are small?

Comment: if Yolo worked with same object size then I suppose this is not the issue

Comment: @Shai I suspect that min and max object sizes at source layers are issues. Let me try. If I set min_dim = 500, all min/max object sizes are calculated based on that. So that value should match to the object sizes.

Comment: @Shai how do you think my discussion for object size and receptive field size discussion in another post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50148376/receptive-feild-size-and-object-size-in-deep-learning`

Answer (score 0):

The issues I found are my training labels for xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax are normalized floating values. SSD needs int (not normalized) values. Then all those feature maps have min and max sizes like conv4_3_norm_mbox_priorbox has min_size: 30.0 and max_size: 60.0. They are calculated based on min_dim = 300. If you change this min_dim value, all min/max sizes are changed and if these sizes don't fit to objects in training, the detection_eval value is low.